# Loop over JSON api

Tags: javascript, json

I have an API call which returns an object, I would like to check if some of the values returns null.

API response structure looks like:

```
{
    "expirationDate": "August 31, 2016",
    "remainingDays": 127,
    "pid": "null",
    "seats": [{
        "activeStatus": "Y",
        "pid": "TE80",
        "firstName": "Lenovo X230 Beta SN",
        "guid": "0CA6A94E378F464E9A5EC09102779CFC"
    }]
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the result a string or is it parsed (= object)? which object from the object? which property is to check?

Comment: i just want to loop to each of the objects to check if some objects returns null then if it is a null then I will show modal which i have one already.

Comment: Do you need the the `pid` from `"pid": "null",`? I mean, Do you need the property keys where the value is `"null"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to iterate through the object keys, and check their values.

The best way, if you put this for loop into a function and then if an object appears, you can use a recursion on that.

```
var json = {
    "expirationDate": "August 31, 2016",
    "remainingDays": 127,
    "pid": "null",
    "seats": [{
            "activeStatus": "Y",
            "pid": "TE80",
            "firstName": "Lenovo X230 Beta SN",
            "guid": "0CA6A94E378F464E9A5EC09102779CFC"
        }]
};

for (prop in json) {
    if (typeof json[prop] === 'object') {
        //do a recursion here
    } else {
        if (json[prop] === 'null') {
            //do what you want with null
            console.log("It is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over all properties and if the value is an array, then over all elements of the array and check if one property value is `null` or `'null'`.

```js
function hasNull(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
        return Array.isArray(o[k]) && o[k].some(hasNull) || o[k] === null || o[k] === 'null';
    });
}

var data = { "expirationDate": "August 31, 2016", "remainingDays": 127, "pid": "null", "seats": [{ "activeStatus": "Y", "pid": "TE80", "firstName": "Lenovo X230 Beta SN", "guid": "0CA6A94E378F464E9A5EC09102779CFC" }] },
    hasNullValue = hasNull(data);

console.log(hasNullValue);
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, this is a big help for me.